# How to I use http.post in angular js to retrieve the rows of my datatable that are checked?

Tags: angularjs, spring, model-view-controller, datatable

Hi I have a datatable with id, name, etc. and have checkboxes added within the angular js

e.g.

```
vm.dtColumns = [
                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle(titleHtml).notSortable()
                    .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        vm.selected[full.ID] = false;
                        return '<input type="checkbox" class="checkedtestids" ng-model="showCase.selected[' + data.ID + ']" ng-click="showCase.toggleOne(showCase.selected)">';
                    }),
```

I have checkboxes that can select all rows from the header or individually.

I have also got a var that keeps the id and changes the boolean state from true to false depending on the checkbox being checked or not.

```
var vm = this;
    vm.message = '';
    vm.someClickHandler = someClickHandler;
    vm.selected = {};
    vm.selectAll = false;
    vm.toggleAll = toggleAll;
    vm.toggleOne = toggleOne;
```

My html code to display this `vm.selected = {};` is as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="WithAjaxCtrl as showCase">

            <blockquote>Please click on a row</blockquote>
            <p class="text-danger">
                You clicked on: <strong>{{ showCase.message }}</strong>
            </p>

            <table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions"
                dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" class="row-border hover"></table>


            <p class="text-danger">You selected the following rows:</p>
            <p>**<pre ng-model="showCase.selected">{{ showCase.selected |json }}</pre**>
```

If I click on these ids :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8GgB.png)

Then the following is reflected below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBj7S.png)

```
{
  "2457937718692": true,
  "2457985718634": false,
  "2454757950532": true,
```

How do I send this array `vm.selected` that indicates checked or not to my java spring controller which will then use them for another purpose?
I have tried to use $http.post() and $http.get() without success.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the ID in the `ng-model` to identify the selected checkboxes because the array of object is bound to the view, instead you can pass the boolean variable and use filter directive https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter.

Eg.:

JAVASCRIPT

```
vm.data = ['a','b','c'];
var selected = [];
var vm.filterSelectedData = function(){
  selected = $filter('filter')(data, {checked: true});
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="element in showCase.data">
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkedtestids" ng-model="element.selected" ng-change="showCase.filterSelectedData()" />
</div>
```

to send the selected items to the server you just need to create a json object with the array of those selected items.

```
http.post('url', {selectedItems:selected})
    .success(function(){ // calback function })
    .error(function(){ // error function })
```

see plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/iJf7onwLUKckQDzBP2pT